# Function with pointer return type

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to understand pointer return types from functions.
The following example produces a type conversion error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* abc(int* y)
{
    int x=y;
    int *z = &x;
    x++;
    return z;
}

int main()
{
  int *a = abc(100);
  int b = *a;
  cout << a <<endl;
  cout << b <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The error message is:-

```
In function 'int* abc(int*)': 6:11: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]  
In function 'int main()': 14:19: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] 
4:6: note: initializing argument 1 of 'int* abc(int*)'
```

How to resolve the above error and also what is the difference between the following function forms and their appropriate calling syntax,

1. int* function()
2. int * function()
3. int *function()

Comment: abc takes a pointer as an input ,you are passing an integer constant (100)

Comment: `int *a = abc(100);` is wrong. You can't take the address of `100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument type in

```
int* abc(int* y)
```

is `int*`. When you call the function,

```
int *a = abc(100);
```

you are passing `100`, an `int`. It is not a pointer to an `int`.

You can fix the problem by using:

**Option 1**

Change the argument type.

```
int* abc(int y) { ... }
```

**Option 2**

Change the way you call the function.

```
int x = 100;
int *a = abc(&x);
```

If you follow this option,

The line

```
int x=y;
```

needs to be modified. Type of `y` is `int*`, not `int`. You'll have to change the line to:

```
int x=*y;
```

**Problem**

You are returning the address of a local variable from the function. Dereferencing that address in the calling function is undefined behavior.

When you return an address from a function and the calling function dereferences that address, the address needs to be valid in the calling function. One way to do that is to allocate memory from heap using `malloc`.

```
int* abc(int* y)
{
    int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = (*y + 1);
    return x;
}
```

When you do that, you'll have to remember to call `free` in the calling function.

```
int x = 100;
int *a = abc(&x);

// Use a

// Deallocate memory
free(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your return type. Your problem is on this line:

```
int x=y;
```

Here `y` is a pointer and you're trying to assign it to `x` which is an `int`.

You're also passing a literal `100` which is an `int` to the `abc` function which takes a pointer as an argument.

Finally, there is no difference between the types of the 3 functions you give. Whitespace is insignificant in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two statements in both functions are incorrect. 100 is not a pointer when `main` calls `abc`, and blindly assigning `y` to `x` won't work because the former is an `int` and the latter is an `int` *pointer.*